# Return Dictionary key, based on value match?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have this **huge** item table / dictionary.

I want to return the `Int16` key value based on the matched string value. I'm trying to auto suggest the `Int16` value based on chosen string in combo box.

I'm not having any issues with my `READ_TABLE` function, it's the `retrieve_ival` function giving me problems.

I'm trying to have the numeric updown's value set based on the string I choose from the combo box, but I want to take that value from the dictionary opposed to storing the values again I already have present. Am I going all wrong about this?

```
public static Dictionary<Int16, string> m_ItemLookup = new Dictionary<Int16, string>
{       
    { 00, "Handgun"},
    { 01, "Handgun SG"},    
    { 02, "Handgun GL" },
    { 03, "Magnum Handgun"},
    { 04, "Magnum Revolver"},
    { 05, "Handgun HP"},
    { 06, "Model 600"},
    { 07, "Revolver"},
    { 08, "Burst Handgun"},
    { 10, "Submachine gun"},
    { 11, "Shotgun"},
    { 12, "Shotgun E"},
    { 13, "Special Hunting Gun"},
    { 14, "Assault Rifle"},
    { 17, "Pill Shooter(White)"},
    { 18, "Pill Shooter(Blue)"},
    { 19, "Mine Detector"},
    { 20, "Rocket Launcher"},
    { 23, "Grenade Launcher (Burst)"},
    { 24, "Grenade Launcher (Flame)"},
    { 25, "Grenade Launcher (Acid)"},
    { 26, "Grenade Launcher (??)"},
    { 27, "Grenade Launcher (BOW GAS)"},
    { 28, "Pesticide Spray"},
    { 29, "Flame Spray"},
    { 30, "Nail Gun"},
    { 31, "Ampoule Shooter"},
    { 100, "Survival Knife"},
    { 101, "Folding Knife"},
    { 102, "Butcher Knife"},
    { 103, "Iron Pipe"},
    { 104, "Curved Iron Pipe"},
    { 105, "Bent Iron Pipe"},
    { 106, "Long Pole"},
    { 107, "Square Timber"},
    { 108, "Stick"},
    { 109, "Axe"},
    { 110, "Scrub Brush"},
    { 111, "Wooden Pole"},
    { 112, "Stick"},
    { 113, "Spear"},
    { 114, "Molotov Cocktail"},
    { 115, "Hammer"},
    { 116, "Crutch"},
    { 117, "Stun Rod"},
    { 118, "Concrete Piece"},
    { 119, "Broken Crutch"},
    { 155, "Empty Bottle"},
    { 157, "Chemical Solvent (green)"},
    { 158, "Yellow Chemical Bottle"},
    { 159, "Gray Chemical Bottle"},
    { 160, "Gray Chemical Bottle"},
    { 200, "Handgun Magazine"},
    { 201, "Handgun SG Magazine"},
    { 202, "Handgun GL Magazine"},
    { 203, "Magnum Clip"},
    { 204, "Revolver Speed Loader"},
    { 205, "Submachine Gun Clip"},
    { 206, "Assault Rifle Clip"},
    { 250, "Handgun Rounds 9mm"},
    { 251, "Magnum HG Rounds"},
    { 252, "Magnum Revolver Rounds"},
    { 253, "Revolver Rounds"},
    { 254, "Shotgun Rounds"},
    { 255, "Rifle Rounds"},
    { 300, "Green Herb" },
    { 301, "Blue Herb" },
    { 302, "Red Herb" },
    { 303, "Green + Green Mixed Herb" },
    { 304, "Green + Green + Green Mixed Herb" },
    { 305, "Green + Red Mixed Herb" },
    { 306, "Green + Blue Mixed Herb" },
    { 307, "Green + Green + Blue Mixed Herb" },
    { 308, "Green + Red + Blue Mixed Herb" },
    { 309, "First Aid Spray" },
    { 310, "Recovery Medicine"},
    { 311, "Hemostat"},
    { 312, "Day Light" },
    { 313, "Blue + Red Mixed Herb"},
    { 314, "Antidote"},
    { 315, "Large Recovery Medicine"},
    { 316, "Anti Virus Pill"},
    { 317, "Large Anti Virus"},
    { 318, "Recovery Medicine Base"},
    { 450, "Lighter"},
    { 451, "Alcohol Bottle"},
    { 452, "Bottle + news Paper"},
    { 453, "Broken Handgun"},
    { 454, "Broken Shotgun"},
    { 455, "Battery"},
    { 456, "Broken Handgun SG"},
    { 12600, "Auxiliary Building Key" },
    { 12601, "Adminstrator's Office Key"},
    { 12602, "Rusty Key"},
    { 12603, "Syringe (empty)"},
    { 12604, "Syringe (Solvent)"},
    { 12605, "Pendant"}, 
    { 14000, "Bolt Cutters"},
    { 14001, "Elephant Key"},
    { 14002, "Alligator Key"},
    { 14003, "Lion key"},
    { 14004, "Office Key"},
    { 14005, "Mr Racoon Medal"},
    { 14006, "Lion Emblem (Red)"},
    { 14007, "Lion Emblem (Blue)"},
    { 14008, "Blank Tape"},
    { 14009, "Parade BGM Tape"},
    { 14010, "Empty entry"}
};

public void READ_TABLE(string fp, ListView LV, ComboBox CMB, bool f_type, RichTextBox Debug_Log) 
{
    LV.Items.Clear();

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fp, FileMode.Open);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

    string[] item_names = new string[0];
    int null_count = 0;

    fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    TBL_HEADER.tag = br.ReadInt32();
    TBL_HEADER.Item_count = br.ReadInt32();

    Debug_Log.AppendText("Defined Item Count: " + TBL_HEADER.Item_count.ToString());

    if (f_type) 
    {
        TBL_HEADER.Item_count *= 3;
    }

    Array.Resize(ref TBL_ITEM, TBL_HEADER.Item_count);
    Array.Resize(ref item_names, TBL_HEADER.Item_count);

    for (int i = 0; i < TBL_HEADER.Item_count; i++) 
    {
        TBL_ITEM[i].Item_val = br.ReadInt16();
        TBL_ITEM[i].Quantity = br.ReadByte();
        TBL_ITEM[i].occurence = br.ReadByte();

        LV.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        LV.Items[i].SubItems.Add(TBL_ITEM[i].Item_val.ToString());

        if (TBL_ITEM[i].Item_val == -1)
        {
            null_count +=1;
            LV.Items[i].SubItems.Add("Null");
            LV.Items[i].ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
            LV.Items[i].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Lucida Console", 9);            
        }

        if (m_ItemLookup.ContainsKey(TBL_ITEM[i].Item_val))
        {                                               LV.Items[i].SubItems.Add(m_ItemLookup[TBL_ITEM[i].Item_val]);
            LV.Items[i].SubItems.Add(TBL_ITEM[i].Quantity.ToString());
            LV.Items[i].SubItems.Add(TBL_ITEM[i].occurence.ToString());
        }
    }

    foreach (string item_name in m_ItemLookup.Values)  // add dictionary values to combo box 
    {
        CMB.Items.Add(item_name);
    }

    Debug_Log.AppendText("\n Total null items Read: " + null_count.ToString());
    fs.Close();
    br.Close(); 
}

public void retrieve_ival(ComboBox cmb, NumericUpDown Ival, NumericUpDown idx) 
{
    int set_key;

    if (m_ItemLookup.ContainsValue(cmb.SelectedText))
    {
        Ival.Value = m_itemLookup; //how do i return key? of the matched value?
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to get `int` value from `string`, why not just make it `Dictionary<string, int>`?

Comment: It appears that combobox contains all entries from your dictionary. Can text in the combobox be typed manually as well?

Comment: @alexm No, its just dumped from the dictionary

Answer (score 2):

Would it be feasible for your program if you swap the keys and values, i.e., using a `Dictionary<string, Int16>`?

If not, remember that a *Dictionary<TKey, TValue>* is also a collection of key-value pairs `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`. You could therefore use Linq to find a key-value pair with a matching string value and thus get access to its key:

```
KeyValuePair<Int16, string> kvp = m_ItemLookup.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == desiredStringValue);
if (kvp.Value == null)
{
    ... no matching key-value pair found
}

int set_key = kvp.Key;
```

Note that *KeyValuePair<Int16, string>* is a struct. Hence, when *FirstOrDefault(...)* fails to find a matching key-value pair, it will return a *KeyValuePair<int, string>* struct with its fields set to the respective default values. The integer key in this struct would be `0`, and the string value would be `null`. Hence the `if` statement which checks whether the string value of the key-value pair is `null` to detect the 'no matching key-value pair found' condition.

This of course will only work reliably as long as you do not store `null` values in the dictionary. If `null` values would be permissible for your dictionary, then do not use *FirstOrDefault(...)*, but instead use a `foreach` loop to iterate over the key-value pairs to find one whose value matches the  given string.